# Write 'Function output ' into a nice Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I used to work with spark who manages to build automatically nice tables.
Now I use python and beautiful soup to ingest drug data.
This is my code, and I want to build a table containing all the drugs + their related information.

I tried to work with "split" because the informations are splidded with " --- "

But not getting something readable :
Please find below the code + a sample of the results + the structure of tha ideal DataFrame

1- Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_details(url):
   print('details:', url)

   # get subpage
   r = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

   # get data on subpabe
   dts = soup.findAll('dt')
   dds = soup.findAll('dd')

   # display details
    for dt, dd in zip(dts, dds):
        print(dt.text)
        print(dd.text)
        print('---')

        print('---------------------------')

def drug_data():
    url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'

    while url:
         print(url)
         r = requests.get(url)
         soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

         # get links to subpages
         links = soup.select('strong a')
         for link in links:
             # exeecute function to get subpage
             get_details('https://www.drugbank.ca' + link['href'])

        # next page url
         url = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
         print(url)
         if url:
            url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca' + url[0].get('href')
         else:
            break
```

2-The output structure look like :

Name

### 5-methyltetrahydrofolic acid

Accession Number

### DB04789

Type

### Small Molecule

Groups

### Approved, Nutraceutical

Description
5-methyltetrahydrofolic acid is a methylated derivate of tetrahydrofolate. It is generated by methylenetetrahydrofolate reductase from 5,10-methylenetetrahydrofolate and used to recycle homocysteine back to methionine by 5-methyltetrahydrofolate-homocysteine methyltransferases (also called methionine synthases).

The Panda Dataframe should look like:

[image: this]

What do you suggest ?
Best

Comment: Would you please correct the indentation of your code.

Comment: Done thank you for the suggestion

Comment: One remark from my side I think you use Python 3.x and not Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the simplest extension to your existing code, to select only a few columns for the DataFrame, the following can be used as a starting point:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headings=['Name','Accession Number','Type','Groups','Description']   # add more as needed, first hit on each is taken
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=headings)   

def get_details(url):
    global df
    global headings
    print('details:', url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")
    dts = soup.findAll('dt')
    dds = soup.findAll('dd')
    data = {}
    for dt, dd in zip(dts, dds):
        if (dt.text in headings) and (dt.text not in data):
            data[dt.text] = dd.text
    df = df.append(data,ignore_index=True)

def drug_data():
    url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'    
    while url:
         print(url)
         r = requests.get(url)
         soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

         # get links to subpages
         links = soup.select('strong a')
         for link in links:
             # exeecute function to get subpage
             get_details('https://www.drugbank.ca' + link['href'])

        # next page url
         url = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
         print(url)
         if url:
            url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca' + url[0].get('href')
         else:
            break

drug_data()

print df[['Name', 'Accession Number']]
```

(NB the problem with the data in your URLs is you get multiple hits on eg. 'Description') Anyway, hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I obtain an empty dataframe : Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, Accession Number]
Index: []

Comment: @Lizou try running the code on just one page (there are 2500+, too long to test all) but I get 24 drugs from page 1 with this code...

Answer (score 0):

To reach our goal there are some things to do. First of all, you have to convert the parsed HTML file into a Pandas Dataframes. For this, you can use Pandas read_html function. Then you have to merge each of the resulting Pandas Dataframes into one Dataframe. 
To style the output you can use Pandas display-related options as that depends a little on your system I just put three possible options on the top of the script. Feel free to consult [Pandas options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html) for further configuration.

```
### Load the pandas library
import pandas as pd

### Set Pandas settings

# Set max number of displayed columns
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)

# Set max column width
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)

# Prevent pandas linebreak
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_details(url):
    print('details:', url)

    # get subpage
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

    ### Convert the soup object to string 
    #   than you can parse it directly with pandas
    #   this returns a list of dfs therefore, fetch the first list item
    #   return the df to merge it later with the other results
    return pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]


def drug_data():
    url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'

    ### Helper list to store the single drugs Pandas Dataframes
    listOfDrugDfs = []

    while url:

        print(url)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

        # get links to subpages
        links = soup.select('strong a')
        for link in links:

            # exeecute function to get subpage
            ### Extended to append results of function to listOfDrugDfs
            listOfDrugDfs.append(get_details('https://www.drugbank.ca' + link['href']))

        # next page url
        url = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
        print(url)
        if url:
            url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca' + url[0].get('href')
        else:
            break

    ### Merge single results dfs to one big results dataframe
    resultDf = pd.concat(listOfDrugDfs)

    ### Print results
    print(resultDf)

    ### Or return
    #return resultDf
```

Comment: Have you tried to run your proposal please ? @asamoah

Comment: Yes I did. It runs without any errros and proper results. Do you get any errors?

Comment: No problems !! millions of thanks ! I hope this discussion will be helpful to others :)